# how to clone a local git repository whose name contains a `:'?

Tags: git

I'm trying to clone a local git repository.
The repository's name contains a `:'. This is confusing both me and git. I get the following error:

```
~/work/c% git clone ../a::b .
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/work/c/.git/
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ../a: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How would you escape the `:'? For now I'm just changing the name of the original repository :-)

I'm using zshell...

Comment: It is not a zsh problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this shouldn't be possible. If you read the Git URLs section of the [git-pull](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) manpage, you'll see that there's a special syntax that uses the '::' as a separator. More info on this `<transport>::<address>` construct can be found at the [git-remote-helpers](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote-helpers.html) manpage.

As for finagling an interpretation other than this, it appears the expansion is taking place in git, and not in zsh, bash, or your shell of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Does:

```
git clone -- ../a::b .

git clone -- "../a::b" .

git clone --local -- "../a::b" .
```

works better?

- The '`--`' will force git to consider ../a::b . as path parameters, not as options.
- The `--local` might help making Git use the right transport mechanism (a simple local copy)

---

Just to be sure, you could also try using the octal value of the [colon character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29):

```
git clone -- "../a\072\072b" .
```

Comment: nope, i already tried that :-)
maybe i need to change something in my shell config in order for that to work?

Comment: @zshgit: you did add the '`--`' before the repo path?

Comment: yes, the `--' is there. i get the same original error. thanks :-)

Comment: @zshgit: just added the "octal value" trick for the colon character, for you to check.

Comment: thanks! no, even with the octal, git still tries to go remotely: "fatal: '../a\072\072b' does not appear to be a git repository". maybe jcordasc is in the right...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know but perhaps with a UI client like Tortoise it works?

It seems git understand your a::b like a hostname:port...

Have you tried with ""?

Comment: mmh.. tortoise? maybe i need something simpler :-). yes, it seems that the `:' fools it into thinking `hostname:port'.

i tried "blabla" and a\:\:b ...

thanks.